# How to HIDE selective values in a multipick list field at visualforce page according to logged in user

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, multi-select, dynamic

I have a multi-select picklist field 'PermissionsAllowed' at object 'AssignPermissions' with 4 values 'Country A User' , 'Country A Processor', 'Country B User'and  'Country B Processor'.

Now according to the user's country, he should see only relevant picklist value options and hide other two  values.For Example, If the user is from Country A , he/she should see only 'Country A User' and 'Country A Processor' as values in multi-select picklist option.

How can we do this?

PS - here the focus is on 'how to hide selective values from multi select picklist ' thus you can ignore on filter part (based on country).

Answer (score 1):

Using **DescribeFieldResult**  you can get all the values and based on the logic you can filter the necessary values : -

```
public List<SelectOption> getCountryUser(){

    List<SelectOption> countryUser = new List<SelectOption>();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult countryUserPkVal = Schema.ObjectName.FieldName.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = countryUserPkVal.getPicklistValues();
    countryUser.add(new SelectOption('--None--', '--None--'));
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple){
        //Your Logic to check Logged in User Country and what you want show in the VF page      
        countryUser.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
    } 
    return countryUser;           
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking time but what I need is to Hide the values in Multiselect pick list. This code can be used if I have to create a custom multiselect pick list but what I desire to do is use same field but hide selective values

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**  - It doesn't seems possible to use the standard multi select pick list and hide values at UI.

**Turnaround** - You can create multi-select picklist using 2 selectLists one for *Values Available* and another for *Selected Values* to show only desired values from custom field at object ; Use two buttons in between those to select or deselect.

**How do you do this ?**

*Following below Steps*   -

1. take all the values from the picklist using DescribeFieldResult() and filter necessary values. See below code to do this.

   `public List<SelectOption> getToSelectValues(){
   List<SelectOption> countryUser = new List<SelectOption>();
   Schema.DescribeFieldResult countryUserPkVal = Schema.ObjectName.FieldName.getDescribe();
   List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = countryUserPkVal.getPicklistValues();
   for(Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple){
       //Your Logic to filter picklist values

       if(!rightvalues.contains(f.getLabel()) )
       countryUser.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
   } 
   return countryUser;

   }`

   2. For select button write below code

> `public PageReference selectclick(){
>             rightselected.clear();
>            for(String s : leftselected){
>                leftvalues.remove(s);
>                rightvalues.add(s);
>            }
>            return null;
>        }`

3. To get selected values use below function

   > public List getSelectedValues(){
   >           List options1 = new List();
   >           List tempList = new List();
   >           tempList.addAll(rightvalues);
   >           tempList.sort();
   >           for(String s : tempList)
   >               options1.add(new SelectOption(s,s));
   >           return options1;
   >           }
4. for deSelect/unselect use below code

   `public PageReference unselectclick(){ 
           leftselected.clear();
           for(String s : rightselected){
               rightvalues.remove(s);
               leftvalues.add(s);
           }
           return null;
       }`
5. Finally to the VisualForce page, paste below code

> `<apex:panelGrid columns="3" id="panelGridId">
>               <apex:selectList id="sel1" value="{!leftselected}" multiselect="true" style="width:223px"  size="4">
>                   <apex:selectOptions value="{!ToSelectValues}" id="firstOptions" />
>               </apex:selectList> 
>                   <apex:panelGroup >
>                       <br/>
>                       <apex:image url="{!$Resource.selectImage}" height="20px" style="cursor:pointer;">
>                           <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!selectclick}" reRender="panelGridId"/>
>                       </apex:image>
>                       <br/><br/>
>                       <apex:image url="{!$Resource.unSelectImage}"  height="20px">
>                           <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!unselectclick}" reRender="panelGridId"/>
>                       </apex:image>
>                   </apex:panelGroup>
>               <apex:selectList id="sel2" value="{!rightselected}" multiselect="true"  style="width:223px" size="4">
>                   <apex:selectOptions value="{!SelectedValues}" />
>               </apex:selectList>`

PS- do not forget to define the variables and initialize them before using

```
Public List<string> leftselected{get;set;}
Public List<string> rightselected{get;set;}
Set<string> leftvalues = new Set<string>();
Set<string> rightvalues = new Set<string>();
```